# is regex faster than if else?

Tags: c++, regex

I have a webserver program to process requests from browser, which is written in c++. There are lots of services, bbs/wiki/news, to name just a few. They have different url, for instance:

1. /bbs/viewtopic?tid=1
2. /wiki/doc?did=1
3. /news/artical?aid=1

now I do URI parse myself, then do if else. I'll take bbs as an example here, if string starts with /bbs/, bbs will take over then following process, then bbs will continue to check if it is viewtopic, if so, sever will sent topic content to client side...

I have a lot of if else to dispatch request to different service, meanwhile, each service has a lot if else to do different actions as well.

I don't know whether if else is a smart choice, even thoug codes are easy to understand.
Is regex is faster for such application?

Thanks for your participation:)

Comment: Regex match vs if/else seems to be apples and oranges here.  Perhaps you are using a different "match" method with your if/else that would be better to compare?

Comment: Benchmark it yourself - it's quite simple (and more accurate than people's opinions).

Comment: In general no.  Just measure it.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, generic programming frameworks (which include using a regex) result in slower code that is faster to write.  What a regex library will probably get you is a lot of time saved writing code at the price of an unimportant amount of CPU time.  More often bottlenecks will be things like bandwidth, disk io and CPU usage by a database (if it's on the same machine).

If it's that important, I will say definitively that you can get faster code by avoiding a regex library, but you should benchmark your implementation, if for no other reason than being able to improve it.  I haven't tested one in C++ to know how efficient they are, but testing the routines in a sample program would be little extra work.

Answer (score 4):

If your `if/else` simply checks the string's prefix, then it would be faster. If it is something more complicated, requiring multiple passes over the string, then you should measure performance yourself.

> Great engineering comes from creating predictable results at
>   predictable costs. In fact, I like to say that if you’re not measuring
>   you’re not engineering.
>
> *Rico Mariani*

Comment: hi i want to check first two character of name... which one is faster if/else or regex for large number of names.

Comment: @LalitKumar, if/else, but if it's a name, you might want to think whether Unicode-aware comparison is required.